# Move a source code project within a collection in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

Is there a (not too difficult) way to do what is depicted in the following image when using TFS 2015?

[Excerpt from Source Control explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHvb.png)

We have a source code project, "Solvency", that we would like to move so that it becomes a child of "Corporate Systems". And, we want the history to be intact.

Comment: We cannot do that straightforward, even though we can move the folder cross team projects, but the folder history will be lost, the fie history within the folder will be saved. The project relationship will also be messed. Daniel's answer would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code can't be moved easily across team project boundaries. The most straightforward way is to just do a tip migration, where you take the current version of the source code and check it in manually.

If you need to maintain history, you'll have to look at migration tools. Depending on the complexity of the structure you have, you may be able to just use `git-tf` or `git-tfs` to convert the TFVC repo into a Git repo, then use the tool again to play back the changes in the Git repo into the target TFVC repo.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I suspected something like this. Migrating from TFVC to Git first seemed like an appealing solution. However, we have a shitload of binary assets (our Main branch is approx. 15 GB!) and over 10 years of history. As I understand it, after some googling, this might be a bit too cumbersome to migrate. I guess we’ll have to live with it as it is or abandon the current project in favor of brand new, historyless (and hopefully a lot slimmer) “clone”.

Comment: @Andvik Git would only be an intermediate step to preserve history. But yes, with a repo of that size, it would likely take a long time.